# Multiple Case statement not working with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I am completely new to mysql and do not have any education in programming. I learn everything by myself by searching tutorials and by reading answers here in stackoverflow. My problem here is that my statement does not output anything nor any error. So I total don't understand what's happening in the code. As my schema and statement are a bit long, I made an sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21e7e/5) so that you can test yourself.

Here is the output I expect. Please help me.

[image]

Here is my attempted query:

```
SELECT regd, Subject, Section, Test_date,
 (CASE WHEN (Name_of_exam = 'First Unit Exam'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Second Unit Exam'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Third Unit Exam')
 THEN (Mark_score / Full_mark) *25 END) AS t_scored,
 (CASE
 WHEN (Name_of_exam = 'First Unit Exam'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Second Unit Exam'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Third Unit Exam')
 THEN (Full_mark) END) AS t_fm,
 (CASE
 WHEN (Name_of_exam = 'First Term Weekly Test'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Second Term Weekly Test'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Third Term Weekly Test'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Final Term Weekly Test')
 THEN (Mark_score / Full_mark) *25
 END ) AS w_scored,
 (CASE
 WHEN (Name_of_exam = 'First Term Weekly Test'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Second Term Weekly Test'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Third Term Weekly Test'
 OR Name_of_exam = 'Final Term Weekly Test')
 THEN (Full_mark) END ) AS w_fm,
 (CASE
 WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
 THEN (Mark_score / Full_mark) *25
 END ) AS f_scored,
 (CASE
 WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
 THEN (Mark_score) END ) AS score_m,
 (CASE
 WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
 THEN (Mark_score / Full_mark) *25
 END ) AS cce_scored,
 (CASE
 WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
 THEN (Full_mark) END ) AS cce_fm
 FROM exam
 WHERE regd='2321' AND Section='A'
 AND Test_date BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-15'
 GROUP BY Subject
```

Update: There are three unit exams, four weekly tests, one final exam and one CCE from field `Name_of_exam`. 25% of the three unit exams namely First Unit Exam, Second Unit Exam, Third Unit Exam needs to be calculated, which can be calculated of course by dividing the sum of mark scored on the three unit exams by the sum of full_marks of the three unit exams. Secondly, We have four weekly test viz., First Term Weekly Test, Second Term Weekly Test, Third Term Weekly Test and Final Term Weekly Test. And a student can have more than one test in the same subject in all of the weekly tests. I want to calculate 25% of the sum of mark_scored from all of the weekly tests, which can be calculated by dividing the sum of mark scores from all the tests by the sum of fullmarks from all the weekly tests. And I want to take out 25% both from CCE and Final Unit Exam. We have four 25% which means 100 in total.

Comment: You don't have any data between `2013-11-01` and `2013-11-15`, that's why your results are empty.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for pointing out. But Case with Group by seems not working together properly. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` when you're not using any aggregate functions? What are you grouping? I suspect you meant to put `MAX(...)` around all the `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Also your expected output in plain English would also help

Comment: @Barmar Initially I put SUM bot not output as expected

Comment: I'm trying to understand how your query matches up with your desired output. Most of the column names are completely different. Like what does `t_scored` correspond to in the results?

Comment: P.S. Use `IN` rather than a bunch of `OR`ed comparisons.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? Are you trying to get averages, or pivot the table?

Comment: @Barmar I have also tried IN but when it comes to group, it could not output result as I expect. You can clearly see what I am trying to output from the shot. It's a kind of pivot.

Comment: IN has nothing to do with the grouping, it just makes your conditions easier to read.

Comment: @Barmar, `t_scored` corresponds to sum of marks from all First term Unit Exam, Second Term Unit Exam and Third Term Unit Exam and take 25% from from it.

Comment: I figured out that the `X_scored` columns in your query correspond to the `XXX 25%` columns in your sample output, but what do the `X_fm` columns correspond to?

Comment: @Barmar, it is for calculating full mark after adding mark in each subject.

Comment: I understand that. But why is it in the query, but not in the "here is the output I expect"?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for quick response. I added total column. Can this be achieved with rollup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query:

```
SELECT regd, Subject, Section, Test_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Unit Exam', 'Second Unit Exam', 'Third Unit Exam')
                THEN Mark_score
           END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Unit Exam', 'Second Unit Exam', 'Third Unit Exam')
                         THEN Full_Mark
                    END)*25 AS t_scored,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Unit Exam', 'Second Unit Exam' 'Third Unit Exam')
                THEN (Full_mark)
           END) AS t_fm,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Term Weekly Test', 'Second Term Weekly Test', 'Third Term Weekly Test', 'Final Term Weekly Test')
                THEN Mark_score
           END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Term Weekly Test', 'Second Term Weekly Test', 'Third Term Weekly Test', 'Final Term Weekly Test')
                         THEN Full_Mark
                    END)*25 AS w_scored,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam IN ('First Term Weekly Test', 'Second Term Weekly Test', 'Third Term Weekly Test', 'Final Term Weekly Test')
                THEN (Full_mark)
           END) AS w_fm,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
                THEN Mark_score
           END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
                         THEN Full_Mark
                    END)*25 AS f_scored,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam'
                THEN (Mark_score)
           END) AS score_m,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
                THEN Mark_score
           END)/SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
                         THEN Full_Mark
                    END)*25 AS cce_scored,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name_of_exam = 'CCE'
                THEN (Full_mark)
           END) AS cce_fm
FROM exam
WHERE regd='2321' AND Section='A'
GROUP BY Subject
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21e7e/32)

Comment: `w_scored` is not output the desired output 15.57. It outputs 18.81. So what is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I used SUM in place of AVG and the result doesn't change much. In your calculation there is only one different subject for exam or test. But in weekly test, student can have test more than once in same subject. Example, if a student has two tests in English in First Term Weekly Test, then AVG or SUM does not work as it should.

Comment: How are the scores from different tests supposed to be combined? I assumed it should be averages, because you didn't explain it in the question. How did you come up with the desired output 15.57?

Comment: If you sum up the full_mark of First Term Weekly Test, Second Term Weekly Test, Third Term Weekly Test and Final Term Weekly Test, it will be 175 and if you sum up the mark_score from here it will be 109. So in order to calculate 25%, 109/175*25=15.57142857. Thanks for reply. I will edit my question.

Comment: Then it should be `SUM(CASE WHEN blah THEN mark_score END)/SUM(CASE WHEN blah THEN full_score END)*25`

Comment: please edit your question and I will accept it. Thanks once again. You are very helpful.

Comment: I've updated the answer and the fiddle. w_scored is now 15.57 as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a great help to me.